# Cannot start Google Admob Campaign (status always a red triangle)

Tags: admob

I have created an Google Admob campaign to advertize my Android app. Everything is ok when creating but after I click Done, the status of campain is always a red triangle, I have try many time with several settings but it was not OK.
[Red triangle in status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8lZ1.png)

About Ad Design, I use Text Ad, it seems not problem.
I have search on Google this problem but no answer for resolving it.

Answer (score 2):

Per admob documentation red triangle can mean the following (please see https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6177178?hl=en):

- Inactive and there is a problem with the campaign that needs to be fixed.
- Active but the campaign is behind schedule.

Also for house ads campaign type should be "Mediated house ad".

Note: it seems like it is important to have valid billing info in your AdWords account. If you dont have a valid card there your ads would not be served (also house ads which are free). To update this info go to Settings -> Billing. It will open approprite page in AdWords. Be sure to wait some time to take effect, for me it was overnight